# Invalid column name SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me pidieron cambiar dos columnas de una tabla, donde ambas columnas son string's sueltos ('Payment_Method' y 'Evaluation_Format', ahora deberían ser FKs numéricas a dos tablas independientes).

Este es mi script de migración:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ExternalCourses')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Payment_Method' and [system_type_id] = 56) --int
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] ADD PaymentType int; 
        END

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Evaluation_Format' and [system_type_id] = 56)
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] ADD EvaluationFormat int; 
        END

        --HOMOGENEIZAR DATOS STRING VIEJOS Y DATOS NUEVOS EN TABLAS
        UPDATE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] SET Payment_Method = 'Reembolso' where Payment_Method = 'Otro';
        UPDATE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] SET Payment_Method = 'Ninguna' where Payment_Method = 'Ninguno';
        UPDATE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] SET Evaluation_Format = 'Hexacta' where Evaluation_Format = 'HX';
        UPDATE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] SET Evaluation_Format = 'Con evaluación externa' where Evaluation_Format = 'Cert'; 
        UPDATE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] SET Evaluation_Format = 'Todas' where Evaluation_Format = 'Todos';
        
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Evaluation_Format' AND [system_type_id] = 231)  --nvarchar
           AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Payment_Method' AND [system_type_id] = 231))
        BEGIN
            UPDATE C 
            SET C.PaymentType = (SELECT P.ID FROM [dbo].[PaymentTypes] P INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] E ON P.Name = E.Payment_Method and E.id = c.id), 
            C.EvaluationFormat = (SELECT EF.ID FROM [dbo].[EvaluationFormats] EF INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] EC ON EC.Evaluation_Format = EF.Name and EC.id = c.id) 
            from [dbo].[ExternalCourses] C
        END

        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Evaluation_Format' and [system_type_id] = 231)
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] DROP COLUMN Evaluation_Format
        END

        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Payment_Method' and [system_type_id] = 231 )
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses] DROP COLUMN Payment_Method
        END
        
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'PaymentType')
            BEGIN
                EXEC sp_rename 'ExternalCourses.PaymentType', 'Payment_Method', 'COLUMN';
            END 

            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'EvaluationFormat')
            BEGIN
                EXEC sp_rename 'ExternalCourses.EvaluationFormat', 'Evaluation_Format', 'COLUMN';
            END 
        
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE [name] = 'FK_Payment_type')
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses]
                ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_type FOREIGN KEY (Payment_Method) REFERENCES [dbo].[PaymentTypes](Id)
        END

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE [name] = 'FK_Evaluation_format')
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExternalCourses]
                ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Evaluation_format FOREIGN KEY (Evaluation_Format) REFERENCES [dbo].[EvaluationFormats](Id)
        END
        
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        DECLARE @ERRORSEVERITYNUMBER INT
        SET @ERRORSEVERITYNUMBER = ERROR_SEVERITY()

        RAISERROR('Error al migrar datos de paymentType y EvaluationFormat', @ERRORSEVERITYNUMBER, 1)
    END CATCH
    END
```

El problema está en:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Evaluation_Format' AND [system_type_id] = 231)  --nvarchar
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Payment_Method' AND [system_type_id] = 231))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE C 
        SET C.PaymentType = (SELECT P.ID FROM [dbo].[PaymentTypes] P INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] E ON P.Name = E.Payment_Method and E.id = c.id), 
        C.EvaluationFormat = (SELECT EF.ID FROM [dbo].[EvaluationFormats] EF INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] EC ON EC.Evaluation_Format = EF.Name and EC.id = c.id) 
        from [dbo].[ExternalCourses] C
    END
```

Donde `C.PaymentType` es el nombre provisorio de la columna de int, esta sentencia es para migrar y sólo se ejecuta si existen las columnas iniciales de tipo string, el if funciona porque lo probé pero aún así me dice que `C.PaymentType` y `C.EvaluationFormat` no existen, y claro, inicialmente no existen pero primero se crean.

Si ejecuto el script por partes la migración está correcta, no sé que puede pasar.

Comment: Bienvenida Camila Margni a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Según logro entender y en forma conceptual tu problema es que estás referenciando a una columna que no existe. Por más que preguntes antes si existe o no, el "compilador" de SQL verifica el script completo, pero no analiza lógica y si referencias a cualquier objeto, tabla, columna, etc, (aunque esten en un bloque condicional) estos deben existir.

Comment: Exacto, eso ocurre, pero debería ejecutarse el script tal y como está, es decir, se crean las columnas nuevas, se las llena con las viejas, a las viejas las borra y a las nuevas les pone el n ombre de las viejas. debe ejecutarse en distintos ambiantes y varias veces sin que ocurra nada una vez que ya ejecutó. Debo partir acaso el script en dos?

Comment: La solución es replantear lo que estás haciendo, no es lo mejor crear o modificar columnas al vuelo de tablas físicas (con una temporal vaya y pase). Ahora, como solución rápida y nada elegante, podrías crear una sentencia dinámica para "engañar" al compilador SQL

Comment: Perfecto Patricio, con la sentencia dinámica el script se ejecutó de forma acorde, veré si lo puedo replantear de alguna forma, pero salió del apuro, gracias.

Comment: Creo que estos comentarios deberían convertirse en respuesta, ya que explican el problema y dan una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Solución que funcionó - expuesta en este [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405099/invalid-column-name-sql-server#comment725254_405099):

> como solución rápida y nada elegante, podrías crear una sentencia dinámica para "engañar" al compilador SQL

Modifiqué el UPDATE por:

```
SET @sql = 'UPDATE C 
        SET C.PaymentType = (SELECT P.ID FROM [dbo].[PaymentTypes] P INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] E ON P.Name = E.Payment_Method and E.id = c.id), 
        C.EvaluationFormat = (SELECT EF.ID FROM [dbo].[EvaluationFormats] EF INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExternalCourses] EC ON EC.Evaluation_Format = EF.Name and EC.id = c.id) 
        from [dbo].[ExternalCourses] C' 

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Evaluation_Format' AND [system_type_id] = 231)  --nvarchar
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'Payment_Method' AND [system_type_id] = 231))
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
```

Comment: Por favor recuerde [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).